# cannot find symbol(it's there...)

Tags: java, netbeans, maven, compilation

I have the following line in a maven project in netbeans.

```
Projection projection = two.translate(Vector.reg1).projection(direction);
```

two is a Shape instance.

```
public abstract class Shape {
   public double mass;
   public double momentOfIntertia;
   public Vector center;
   public abstract List<Edge> normals(Vector direction);
   public abstract Projection projection(Vector line);
   public abstract Shape transform(Transformation transformation);
   public abstract Shape translate(Vector translation);
   public abstract void render(Graphics graphics);
}
```

and when I compile I get this error.

```
[ERROR]BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Compilation failure

org/curious/pounce/Collision.java:[89,39] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method translate(org.curious.pounce.math.Vector)
location: class org.curious.pounce.Shape
```

I'm not sure what can be wrong with this, if anything was wrong netbeans should be pointing out the error in the IDE, which it isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running a clean on all projects involved (in maven, assuming that's where the message is from).

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing `mvn clean` and then building again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: Netbeans indicates a invalid method but he was there! I tried several ways to resolve this issue without success. So, i upload manually the jar archive into dependence of project: right-click on dependency, right-click on jar-archive, install artifact manually.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem just now. For me, the symbol is in a package, and I'm using maven to manage the code.

Just running:

```
mvn clean install
```

didn't help me, Then I ran:

```
mvn idea:clean idea:idea
```

After this, I found the symbol disappeared, which means the code I saw is not the code I was using. So I think maybe it is because the IntelliJ didn't update the code, which leads to this confusion.